# Loading Garbage values from Database to Listview

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sqlite, android-arrayadapter

I want to Load my database data to the arraylist and then from arraylist to listview on button click but when I clicked the button it loads Garbage data to the listview. This is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Bookmarks.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                    String query = "Insert into WEB values('" + title.getText().toString() + "','" + address.getText().toString() + "')";
                    db.execSQL(query);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bookmark Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               try {
                    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Title FROM WEB", null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    String check = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title"));
                    list.add(check);
                    }
                while (c.moveToNext());
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the screenshot of Layout...

[image]

Comment: If `title` and `address` are `EditText`s, you need to call `getText().toString()` on them to get the actual text.

Comment: @ Mike M. I am fetching a single row in each iteration from Sqlite database which contains both the title and address and then store that records in arraylist.I think it's not possible to call the getText().toString() to fetch the data from the Sqlite database...

Comment: I meant `title` and `address` in the `Insert` command; ya know, the only place in your posted code where you have those variable names.

Comment: Kindly check the updated version, i have added getText().toString() with both title and address, But still It loads garbage values to the listview ...

Comment: You need to clear the database; otherwise it's still got the old values you inserted. Either select "Clear data" in your app's info page in Settings, or uninstall and reinstall the app. You can also do it through adb, but I don't know the command off the top of my head.

Comment: @ Mike M. Have a glance on it now, i have just put a screenshot...

Comment: Read the comment I just posted.

Comment: You are right, but the thing is why it don't show the title and address, it shows Garbage data...

Comment: I don't follow. Are you asking why it did show garbage? Or are you saying it's still showing garbage?

Comment: @Mike M. I just go to Settings and "Clear Data" of my app and now it's working fine, Thanks for your precious time :)